# Web Services in ColdFusion 2016 no longer functional

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, wsdl, apache-axis, axis

I'm upgrading from ColdFusion 9 to **ColdFusion 2016** and my web services suddenly no longer work. I believe it's because **Axis 2** was introduced in Cold Fusion 10 and with it rendered my existing web services non-functional.

Even if I set the Web Service version back to 1 in ColdFusion Administrator, it still doesn't work.

[image]

The way I call these web services is with the `createObject` function as such:

```
<cfscript>
    objSoapHeader = XmlParse("<wsse:Security mustUnderstand=""true"" xmlns:wsse=""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd""><wsse:UsernameToken><wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username><wsse:Password>PASSWORD</wsse:Password></wsse:UsernameToken></wsse:Security>");

    Application.UserWebService = CreateObject("webservice", PATH & "Requests/UserService.asmx?WSDL");
    addSOAPRequestHeader(Application.UserWebService,"","",objSoapHeader,true);

    // Get the .Net resources
    Application.NetResources = Application.UserWebService.GetNetResources(); 

</cfscript>
```

The error I recieve is :

> Cannot perform web service invocation GetNetResources.
>
> The fault returned when invoking the web service operation
>   is:java.lang.RuntimeException: Error obtaining parser from data
>   source:LanguageHeader cannot be null!

It states that the `LangaugeHeader` cannot be `null`. The WSDL displays two messages associated to the `GetNetResources` operation:

```
<wsdl:portType name="UserServiceSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetNetResources">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:GetNetResourcesSoapIn"/>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:GetNetResourcesSoapOut"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType >
```

However when looking at the list of messages I can see three messages associated to GetNetResources:

```
<wsdl:message name="GetNetResourcesSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element=tns:GetNetResources"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetNetResourcesSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element=tns:GetNetResourcesResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="GetNetResourcesLanguageHeader">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element=tns:LanguageHeader"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

<s>*If the operation is only specifying two messages, then where in the WSDL file is this third message being associated to the operation?*</s>

*It seems that the LanguageHeader parameter is absolutely required and enfored in ColdFusion 2016, so why was it working in ColdFusion 9 (Axis 1)?*

**EDIT 1**

To answer my first question above (striked out) I found the following code in the `binding` as opposed to the `portType`:

```
<wsdl:binding name="UserServiceSoap" type="tns:UserServiceSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetNetResources">
        <soap:operation style="document" soapAction="http://tempuri.org/GetNetResources"/>
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
            <soap:header message="tns:GetNetResourcesLanguageHeader" use="literal" part="LanguageHeader"/>
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
```

However that still doesn't answer my second question.

**EDIT 2**

After playing around with the code a bit, I manged to resolve the `RuntimeException` by adding a variable to the web service call.

```
args = {TEST="<locale>en-CA</locale>"};
Application.NetResources = Application.UserWebService.GetNetResources(argumentCollection=args);
```

Which now results in the following error:

> Web service parameter name languageHeader cannot be found in the
>   provided parameters {TEST}.

As `TEST` is not an actual parameter specified in the WSDL, I modified it to `languageHeader`, and recieve this new error:

> Web service operation GetNetResources with parameters {LANGUAGEHEADER={<locale>en-CA</locale>}} cannot be found.

This indicates that `languageHeader` is indeed the correct parameter name, however it still cannot find the the web service operation, therefore I believe the 'type' of the parameter is different.

Perhaps I'm not suppose to be sending a string as the value, however looking back at my WSDL, it states that they type of the `Locale` is a string:

```
<wsdl:types>
    <s:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" elementFormDefault="qualified">
        <s:element name="LanguageHeader" type="tns:LanguageHeader"/>
        <s:complexType name="LanguageHeader">
            <s:sequence>
                <s:element name="Locale" type="s:string" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0"/>
            </s:sequence>
            <s:anyAttribute/>
        </s:complexType>
    </s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

From what I understand I'm suppose to be sending a `complexType` object as the parameter which contains a `Locale` as a string.

*What kind of object would I be sending from CFML if that is the case?*

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but did you do a `refreshWSDL=true` to verify it is not something silly like caching? :)

Comment: I have when I tried using `cfinvoke` and it still doesn't work

Comment: Ok. Just verifying the WS object really was *re*created with version 1 (in the proper scope). I do not have access to 2016 right now, but it is always possible something changed. Sorry I could not be of more help.

Comment: I believe the change was from ColdFusion 9 to 10 simply because [Axis 2](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSe61e35da8d318518-2fbb29ff1353e865893-8000.html) was introduced

Comment: If you have time, you could confirm it by [downloading commandbox](https://www.ortussolutions.com/products/commandbox) and running the code with CF10. Just to see if it throws the same error.

Comment: Sadly I don't have ColdFusion 10 installed, but it's good to know this tool exists, thanks!

Comment: *Sadly, I don't have ColdFusion 10 installed* That is what commandbox is for :-) It makes it pretty easy to [spin up different versions](https://ortus.gitbooks.io/commandbox-documentation/content/embedded_server/multi-engine_support.html). Essentially, just download the latest, run `box.exe` (assuming windows). From the box CLI, run `start cfengine=adobe@10 port=8500`. It will automatically download and install that version, then start it on the given port number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When [consuming a web service with a parameter of a complex data type](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-78b2.html), send a `structure` as the parameter.

```
// Create struct
stLanguageHeader = structNew();
stLanguageHeader.locale = "en-CA";

Application.NetResources = Application.UserWebService.GetNetResources(stLanguageHeader);
```